# get date in Month Name, day format xslt?

Tags: xslt, date, format

How do we get the date formatted in xslt like this October,18?

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate) ,1044 ,'MM.dd.yyyy')" />
```

How do we change the format from the numerical MM to the Month name, dd and remove year?Please someone help!

Comment: What is the value of `@ArticleStartDate` ?

Comment: @AjKancha - Right, but in what format?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, `ddwrt:FormatDateTime` uses CLDR time formats. Then you can follow the documentation on [unicode.org](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time)

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 has

```
format-date(@startDate, "[MNn], [D1]", "en", (), ())
```

You don't say which XSLT version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with XSLT 1.0:

```
FormatDate(string szDate, long lcid, long formatFlag);
```

formatFlag can obly be a number from 0 to 15

```
<xsl:variable name="time" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate), 1033, 3)" />
<xsl:variable name="subtime" select="substring-after($time, ',')" />
<xsl:variable name="restime" select="substring-before($subtime, ',')" />
<xsl:value-of select="$restime" />
```

Result format: **May 7**

[Read more on ddwrt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdate)

[Read more on string operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdate)

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT. There is no `ddwrt` in XSLT and no `FormatDate()` in XSLT 1.0

Comment: `ddwrt` is mentioned in the question.